# Git alias does not print output of command

Tags: git, git-alias, git-diff-tree

I have the following git alias

```
[alias]  
remaster = !"git checkout $1 & git diff-tree -r --patch --diff-filter=DM $1..master"
```

When using the above command by hand I get the following stdout:

```
$ git diff-tree -r --patch development..master --diff-filter=DM

diff --git a/subfolder/subfile.exe b/subfolder/subfile.exe
deleted file mode 100644
index e69de29..0000000
diff --git a/virus.exe b/virus.exe
deleted file mode 100644
index e69de29..0000000
```

When using the alias the output is not available therefore I cannot use it to patch:

```
$ git remaster development
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git aliases are mainly designed to call *one* other *git* command, not more than one arbitrary commands. That is, you usually do something like

```
[alias]
    aa = commit --amend -a --no-edit
```

Note that the above only says `commit`, not `git commit`. Anyway, there's a common trick to still achieve what you want, by using a dummy shell function:

```
[alias]
    remaster = "!f() { git checkout $1 && git diff-tree -r --patch --diff-filter=DM $1..master | git apply; }; f"
```

(I've also changed the single `&` to correctly say `&&`.)